# Display items grouped in month together using django regroup

Tags: django, django-templates, django-annotate

I have a model with following fields

```
examname | month 
a1          Jan    
a2          Jan    
a3          Jan    
b1          Feb    
b2          March  
b3          March
```

I want to display exams in each month grouped in months

example

```
Jan : a1 a2 a3 
Feb : b1
March: b2 b3
```

I am using the following queryset

```
def getallexams(request):
    exams = exam.objects.annotate(month_total=Count('month')).order_by('month')
    print(exams)
    context={
        "exams" : exams,
        }
    return render(request, 'exams/index.html',context)
```

Below is the code I am using to render the template:

```
{% regroup exams by month as month_list %}
 <div class="accordion" >
 {% for month in month_list %}
 {{month.grouper }}
 # I am not sure how to loop through this month to display each exam
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation has a pretty nice description of how to use regroup tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/

```
{% regroup exams by month as month_list %}
<div class="accordion" >
{% for month in month_list %}
  {{month.grouper }}
  {% for exam in month.list %}
     {{ exam.examname }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```